# Child Views do not expand to the same height as their parent

Tags: android-layout, height, match, parent, listitem

I've got the following setup:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        <!--otherwise nothing important is happening here -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_item"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/undo_acknowledge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|start"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/undo"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/acknowledge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="fill_vertical|end"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Some background:**

I've got a Recycler View containing these layout as list items. When I slide an item, the LinearLayout (I've tried also RealtiveLayout) "sliding_layout" becomes visible and it's two TextViews appear.
The "list_item" layout's height is calculated using wrap_content and therefore the "sliding_layout" uses

```
  android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_item"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list_item"
```

to match it's height.

Up to this point it works fine. But I want the two child TextViews of "sliding_layout" to have the same height as their parent (and therefore as "list_item"). As you can see, I tried to achieve this by multiple ways (all of them separate and combined, as far as possible):

- android:layout_height="match_parent"
- android:gravity="fill_vertical"
- android:layout_alignParentTop="true" &       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" (with RealtiveLayout as parent)

But none of those seems to do anything: The vertical size of the TextViews seems to be calculated according to the text size.

My Build configuration is the following:

- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 21

Do you have any suggestions what I could do to achieve getting my TextViews the same height as their parent?

Comment: I am having same problem, have you found any solution?